# Flexbox grow is not making one element fill all of the empty space, and some magic whitespace is being made 

Tags: javascript, html, css, tailwind-css

I want to achieve it so that the email box stretches all the way and touches the sign up button.

[image: screenshot]

Here is my code which I have used to try and do it right now:

```html
<div class="mb-12 inline-block">
    <h1 class="text-7xl font-bold mt-9">A better way to</h1>
    <h1 class="indent-9 text-7xl font-bold text-[#6E6BFF]">store your code</h1>

    <div class="mt-12 max-w-[610px]">
        <p class="mb-8">With RepoZoid, storing your own code is as easy as pie. Just add a new entry, paste your code in - and you're off to the races.</p>
        <p>It's as simple as 1, 2, 3 - with sharing options and more coming in the future!</p>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-row">
        <div class="grow">
            <input class="w-[100%] text-[#9c9ea5] py-3 px-4 rounded-md" placeholder="Enter your email" type="email" name="emailinput">
        </div>

        <div class="flex grow justify-end">
            <button class="px-4 py-3 rounded-md bg-[#6E6BFF] text-white">Sign Up</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Kind Reguards,

Henry.

Comment: the button wrapping div should not have `grow`. instead of `flex grow justify-end`, use `ml-4`. Additionally use built-in classes instead of creating random ones (`w-[100%]`is equivalent to `w-full`)

Comment: Thank you ever so much, do you mind putting this into a solution for others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on AngelSalazar's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70899353/flexbox-grow-is-not-making-one-element-fill-all-of-the-empty-space-and-some-mag#comment125338597_70899353):
The wrapper div for the button should not have `grow`. Instead of `flex grow justify-end`, use `ml-4`.